# How do I make a SQL query to select all items that contain a certain sub-string?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example I have a table named "location" and a column "name". I want all names that contain the sub-string "abe" for example. I am using postegresql.

Comment: `where column like '%abe%'`

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mention postgresql in your tag you should have a look at the PostgreSQL documentation.

There is a topic about [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html)

One solution for your query would be:

```
select *
from location
where name like '%abe%'
```

LIKE is also explained on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_like.asp).

Comment: You need some quotes around the string literal.

Comment: @jarlh ty, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT name FROM location WHERE name LIKE '%abe%';

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LIKE keyword, same as in TSQL. See the link below.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_like_clause.htm

Comment: Same as in TSQL, why mention that to a Postgresql user?

Comment: To be honest. . .I have no idea. It is the DB language I am accustomed to, but I see now that would be completely irrelevant to other users

Answer (score 1):

if you need ignore match case, you can use `ILIKE`

```
where column ILIKE '%abe%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME FROM LOCATION WHERE NAME REGEXP 'abe';
```